# Can phone gap web sql can work with android notification manager?

Tags: android, cordova, notificationmanager

Is it possible to work with android notification manager
With phonegap? And show data of the notification from the web sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course its possible. However, I think you will have to code the notification 'natively' as android code; coding it in Phonegap code(javascript) may not be possible.

As for web sql, do you mean you want to pull the data from a sqllite database?

Comment: I have to do list app and my data stored in the web sql , so my question is if i can pull this data to sqlite db for using it with the native notification manager

Comment: Not sure about this one, have never tried, but somehow I feel this is going to be painful, if at all possible